# Sequelize - how to use operator AND in association n:n

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

With Sequelize, I have two models with many to many association : Movie and Actor.
I want to get all movies that movies that with to the current actors, but I don't understand how do.

get method:

```
http://localhost:3333/movie?actors=Keanu Reeves&actors=Ian McShane
```

```
Movie.findAll({
      where: { ...movieQuery },
      attributes: ['name', 'director', 'genre'],
      include: [
        {
          model: Actor,
          where: { ...actorsQuery },
          attributes: ['name'],
          through: {
            attributes: [],
          },
        },
      ],
    }),
```

result:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7uIL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Considering below translates as follows:

```
User.findAll({include: [{model: Post, where: {active: true}}]
INNER JOIN `posts` AS `post` ON `users`.`id` = `post`.`user_id` AND `post`.`active`=true
```

I believe it's enough if you specify query for the table being joined:

```
var actors = [{'name': 'Keanu Reeves'}, {'name': 'Ian McShane'}];
Movie.findAll({
  attributes: ['name', 'director', 'genre'],
  include: [
    {
      model: Actor,
      where: { [Op.or]: actors },
      attributes: ['name'],
      through: {
        attributes: [],
      },
    },
  ],
}),
```

Maybe you'll have to remove duplicates, not sure. **Please notice** that spaces in an URL:

```
http://localhost:3333/movie?actors=Keanu Reeves&actors=Ian McShane
```

should be encoded:

```
http://localhost:3333/movie?actors=Keanu%20Reeves&actors=Ian%20McShane
```